# Javascript, contain image inside windows edges

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn more javascript and right now I'm just playing around with the event listener method. I've made a simple HTML document with a div that contains a background image. I've successfully made the image move upon the correct key press. What I want to do now is prevent the image to pass the edges of the window.

I know that window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight gives me the size of the window, but I can't figure out how to use this to restrict the image's movement.

The html:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="code.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Inside the style.css:

```
 body{

}
#image{
    position: absolute;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;

    background: url("../img/image.png");

    background-size: 80px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

And inside the code.js:

```
(function() {
    var image;

    var count, left, top;

    image = document.getElementById('image');
    count = 30;

    left = 200;
    top = 200;

    image.style.left = left + "px";
    image.style.top = top + "px";

    document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
        var key = event.keyCode || event.which;

        left = image.offsetLeft;
        top = image.offsetTop;

        switch(key) {
            case 37:
            left -= count;
            break;
            case 38:
            top -= count;
            break;
            case 39:
            left += count;
            break;
            case 40:
            top += count;
            break;
       }
       image.style.left = left + "px";
       image.style.top = top + "px";
});
});
```

PS. I only want to use vanilla JavaScript for this. No jQuery please. :)

Comment: Seems that big chunks of code are missing?

Comment: As I said, I'm trying to learn. But the above code does work. I just ran it in my web browser and it works fine. Anything you can tell me that should be in the code but isn't?

Comment: @Chi You are missing curly brackets and brackets.

Comment: Aah, I put it in by hand so I missed some brackets and such. Should be fixed now. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limiting its movement to the left and top of your window should be very straight-forward.  When the image is at the top of the screen, its offsetTop will be 0.  And at the left, its offsetLeft will be 0.  So you can add this after your switch statement:

```
if (left < 0) {
    left = 0;
}
if (top < 0) {
    top = 0;
}
```

That's too verbose though.  I prefer to use Math.min() and Math.max() -- these are built-in Javascript functions.  So instead, I recommend you do this:

```
left = Math.max(0, left);
top  = Math.max(0, top);
```

Now, the right and bottom boundaries are a little trickier.  You've already discovered offsetLeft and offsetTop.  An element also has offsetWidth and offsetHeight properties.  These represent the number of rendered pixels an element takes up from the outer edges of its border.  We won't get in to all the details now.
You've also found window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight.  So, you might say that the maximum left coordinate should be `window.innerWidth - image.offsetWidth`.  Again, we could do this with 'if' statements, but I prefer using the built-in Math functions for this purpose.

```
left = Math.min(left, window.innerWidth - image.offsetWidth);
top  = Math.min(top, window.innerHeight - image.offsetHeight);
```

So, add those 4 lines after your switch statement and Voila! Your image will be constrained to the limits of your window.

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick! I didn't even think about using the Math functions.

Comment: No problem.  Javascript has lots of nifty tricks.  Do you know about Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) yet?  It's the resource most of us go to when we want to learn about anything JS-related.  Just Google whatever you're curious about and add "MDN" to the end and I'll bet they've got extensive information about it.  Happy learning!  Oh, and if you're really new to JS and want a fun way to learn, you could check out http://www.codecademy.com/ It's kinda neat.  It has badges and achievements and makes a bit of a game out of it.